# SQL - Combining duplicate rows from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a query that returns the top 5 best selling titles. Some titles have multiple authors, creating multiple rows of the same title taking up the spots.

`GROUP BY` is not grouping the like titles together and `DISTINCT` doesn't work as well.

```
select top 5 
    t.sales,
    t.title_name, 
    (a.au_fname + ' ' + a.au_lname) as author,
    (t.price * t.sales) as revenue
from titles t
join title_authors ta on ta.title_id = t.title_id
join authors a on a.au_id = ta.au_id
group by 
    t.title_name, 
    t.sales, 
    (a.au_fname + ' ' + a.au_lname),
    (t.price * t.sales)

order by t.sales desc
```

outputs:
[image: duplicate rows]

When I put `DISTINCT` in front of `TOP` it still gives me the same output.

I want the titles that are duplicated to be combined, only showing one author.

These are the tables I'm working with: 'titles', 'title_authors', and 'authors'
[image: tables]

Thanks to @Venkataraman-R for the solution:

with slight changes to his code I have the exact output I'm looking for

```
SELECT TOP 5 
    t.sales, 
    t.title_name,
    string_agg((a.au_fname + ' ' + a.au_lname),';') as 'author(s)',
    (t.price * t.sales) as revenue
from titles t
join title_authors ta on ta.title_id = t.title_id
join authors a on a.au_id = ta.au_id
group by t.title_name, t.sales, (t.price * t.sales)
ORDER BY  t.sales DESC
```

[image: solution]

Comment: Please provide us with sample data and expected results?

Comment: Hi Sirildo, just wanted to point out that the revenue figure is being misrepresented on the query, it's getting multiplied by the number of authors on each title, not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @JorgeGarcia  Please look into my updated code. I have put MAX function to get proper revenue figures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the SQL Server version as 2016 and writing the below query. I am using STRING_AGG for aggregating the author names for titles.

```
SELECT TOP 5 t.title_name,string_agg((a.au_fname + ' ' + a.au_lname),';'), max(t.price * t.sales) as revenue
from titles t
join title_authors ta on ta.title_id = t.title_id
join authors a on a.au_id = ta.au_id
group by t.title_name
ORDER BY  revenue DESC
```

Comment: With some slight changes you've helped me out!

Comment: Happy to note. If it answered your question. make it as answer, it will be helpful for others in future

Comment: Venkataraman R, query misrepresents the revenue figure (it's getting multiplied by the number of authors on each title)

Comment: @JorgeGarcia, Sorry. my bad. I should have tested it. I have corrected the code. Thanks for pointing the mistake

Answer (score 1):

Leave author out of your group by clause, calculating best selling titles does not need data from the authors table.

```
select top 5 t.sales, t.title_name, 
(t.price * t.sales) as revenue
from titles t

group by t.title_name, t.sales,
(t.price * t.sales)

order by t.sales desc
```

If you need your final result to include a list of authors per title, you can join this result with the authors table later like this:

```
with combined_title_authors as
(
     select title_id, author_name = STRING_AGG(a.au_fname + ' ' + a.au_lname, ', ')
    from title_authors ta
    inner join authors a on a.au_id = ta.au_id
    group by ta.title_id
)

select top 5 t.sales, t.title_name, a.author_name,
(t.price * t.sales) as revenue 
from titles t

join combined_title_authors a
on a.title_id = t.title_id

group by t.title_name, t.sales,
(t.price * t.sales), a.author_name

order by t.sales desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/21f2a/16

Answer (score 0):

If you want latest author you can use the following

```
SELECT TOP 5 t.sales, t.title_name, (a.au_fname + ' ' + a.au_lname) as author, (t.price * t.sales) as revenue
    FROM titles t
    JOIN (SELECT  [title_id],max([au_id]) AS au_id
        FROM [test].[dbo].[title_authors] GROUP BY dbo.title_authors.title_id ) as ta on ta.title_id = t.title_id
    JOIN authors a on a.au_id = ta.au_id
    GROUP BY  t.title_name,  t.sales, (a.au_fname + ' ' + a.au_lname), (t.price * t.sales)
    ORDER BY  t.sales DESC
```